# Vuejs: component aggregation

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Starting from the following simple reddit-like example : https://jsfiddle.net/coligo/g7mu5ndz/

```
Vue.component('post', {
  template: "#post-template",
  props: ['post'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      upvoted: false,
      downvoted: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    upvote: function () {
      this.upvoted = !this.upvoted;
      this.downvoted = false;
    },
    downvote: function () {
      this.downvoted = !this.downvoted;
      this.upvoted = false;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    votes: function () {
      if (this.upvoted) {
        return this.post.votes + 1;
      } else if (this.downvoted) {
        return this.post.votes - 1;
      } else {
        return this.post.votes;
      }
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    posts: [{
        title: "A post for our reddit demo starting at 15 votes",
        votes: 15
      },
      {
        title: "Try out the upvoting, it works, I promise",
        votes: 53
      },
      {
        title: "coligo is the bomb!",
        votes: 10
      }]
  }
});
```

I'd like to :

- a) Display the total number of upvotes (under the list of posts, in the #app div
- b) For each post, display the percentage of total upvotes it has gained

Is this possible without managing each post state in the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is too much refactoring that needs to be done to code which can't be explained here. So here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/3yveuj02/1/)

I'll just point out the key changes:

- You are adding and subtracting votes on the component but you are getting data via props , so you should update the parent by emitting an event. Useful links: [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events), [props are one-way](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)
- You can use a computed property to calculate total votes in the parent ass now upvotes and downvotes are making changes to main data present in parent
- pass the total votes from parent to child component as props to calculate percentage votes

  ```
       Vue.component('post', {
     template: "#post-template",
     props: ['post', 'total'],
     data: function () {
       return {
         upvoted: false,
         downvoted: false,

       };
     },
     computed:{
         percentVotes(){
           return (this.post.votes/this.total * 100).toFixed(2)
         }
     },
     methods: {
       upvote: function () {
         if(!this.upvoted){
             this.upvoted = true;
             this.downvoted = false;
             this.$emit('upvoted');
         }

       },
       downvote: function () {
         if(!this.downvoted){
             this.downvoted = true;
             this.upvoted = false;
             this.$emit('downvoted');
         }
       }
     }
   });

   var vm = new Vue({
     el: "#app",
     data: {
       posts: [{
                   title: "A post for our reddit demo starting at 15 votes",
                   votes: 15
               },
               {
                   title: "Try out the upvoting, it works, I promise",
                   votes: 53
               },
               {
                   title: "coligo is the bomb!",
                   votes: 10
               }]
     },
     methods: {
         upvoted(post){
             post.votes = post.votes +1;
         },
         downvoted(post){
             post.votes = post.votes - 1;
         }
     },
     computed:{
         totalVotes(){
           var postVotes = this.posts.map((post) => {
                 return post.votes;
             });

             var getTotal = function (total, num) {
               return total + num;
            }
            return postVotes.reduce(getTotal);
         }
     }
   });
  ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the custom events doc, that was the missing piece of the puzzle. This ends up with most of the logic in the parent, but I guess it is the way to go, and it works perfectly.